# Android setEGLContextClientVersion() is not registering properly

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es-2.0

For whatever reason, my EGL Context Client Version isn't getting set in my OpenGL application. I setup the context by simply doing the following:

```
final boolean supportEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

        if (supportEs2) { //<-- this resolves to true.


            mGLView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

            try {
                mGLView.setRenderer(new PongDroidRenderer(getApplicationContext()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And after that, I get a runtime exception when trying to compile a shader due to the context not being called correctly. After some research, I figured out that I'm unable to call OpenGL from the **main thread**, however, as far as I know my application itself *isn't* multi-threaded (of course, the system is however). So, I'm kind of hoping to see if anyone here would have any idea as to how I can get this working, and if more information is provided just say the word and I'll post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a glSurfaceView? The opengl context is only valid from the surfaceview thread (the one that calls onDrawFrame, onSurfaceChanged, onSurfaceCreated, etc). You should compile your shaders in those callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the minimum supported API version of Android to 8, as the OpenGL 2.0 is supported in Android 2.2 and higher. If you set the version to lower, you must call the `setEGLContextClientVersion()` method either in `onSurfaceCreated()`, `onSurfaceChanged()` or `onDrawFrame()` as Tim said.